# Get webContentLink from google drive api with converted document

Tags: web-applications, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive with REST calls. I want to upload any kind of file to client's drive. I use two links from google drive in my web application, the "visualization" and "download" links.

I get download link from "webContentLink" json property, and visualization link from "alternateLink".

Some files like spreadsheets, documents and plain text must be converted, so I set the "convert" parameter to "true".

**The problem**

with the file sent is converted to another google docs type, the json returned doesn't have the "webContentLink" property! How can I have both links **download** and visualization when I'm working with converted document files?

**EDITED**

I'm looking for the download link for the original file uploaded before it's converted. If I upload an xls for example, I would like to have a download link for the original xls file.
With "exportLinks" list, I have a bunch of links for xlsx, but I have no way to get "the right one", the mime types in "exportLinks" are different from the original file mimeType. And for some files, one of the two spreadsheet exportLinks given is broken...

Comment: Are you sure the title of your post is related to your question body ?

Comment: Thankyou, the stackoverflow cookie tricked me, it was from a old question, I didn't look at title jus edited the body... Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want download links for google native documents, you have to fetch the `exportLinks` properties of the JSON returned.

You will have several of them, depending on the format of the file. One at least is common to all native format, the one with `"application/pdf"` mime type.

Comment: But this way I have the original file converted to pdf. I would like to get a link to the original file.
An xls for example, I would like to get an link for the original xls file.

Comment: You then need to prevent the conversion of your file. Or it exists an exportLink for xls format. The problem is that your document will be doubly converted. Expect some weird things if you chose that solution and not the former

Comment: I decided to follow your advice since it's the best one, so I'm using the exportLinks no, but not only the "pdf/application". I'm using the right mimeType for each file but the "exportLinks" are for visualization and not download. Do you know what to do with this exportLinks to create a download link for the file?

Comment: exportLinks work for download. An authorized GET method on those links should do the trick